How to select range by just two click in Scheduler Timeline
Here's https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/timeline I want to select a date range. For example, if I choose the start date, I want to select the second date only if it's greater than the first one, to form a range. I mean, I want to select the first cell, and then when I select the second cell.
I want to have the range selected between them. I don't want to drag the mouse or use the Shift key to do it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
